# Number of Rows in a Full Join (DB2 - SQL)

Tags: sql, db2

I am running a DB2/SQL - FULL JOIN query.

```
    PROC SQL;
    CONNECT TO db2 AS db1 (USER=&dpwuscod. PASSWORD=&dpwpwcod.  DATABASE=&dpwdbnam.);

    CREATE TABLE result3 AS 
    SELECT * 
    FROM   CONNECTION to db2 
     ( 
              SELECT     count(* ) as NbrCount
              FROM        a
              FULL JOIN   b 
              ON         a.pk = b.pk
              AND      a.snap_dt='2015-08-31' 
              AND        a.sys_num not in ('1234')

      );
    DISCONNECT FROM db2;
    QUIT;
```

Table A has 586,648 rows. Table B has 2,384,874 rows.

I was expecting the number of rows in the FULL Join to be between 2,384,874 (when there is a complete overlap of the PK) to 2,971,522 (when the two tables have Mutually Exclusive PK / 2,971,522 = 586,648 + 2,384,874)

However, in actuality, the above join is yielding NbrCount = 24,898,361.

Any pointers on why the number of rows has blown up?

Comment: don't do a count(*). do `select *`, and you'll see why you're getting that count - it's a full join - you're going to get `null` values for either side of the join where no proper match exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because some `pk`s have duplicate matches.  This is easy enough to find:

```
select pk, count(*)
from a
group by pk
having count(*) > 1;

select pk, count(*)
from b
group by pk
having count(*) > 1;
```

Of course, you can restrict the conditions to use your filters.

And, perhaps you want `count(distinct coalesce(a.pk, b.pk))` in your `select` clause.  That would count the number of rows being returned from each table, with no duplicates on the rows.

Comment: Thanks. Table a is an EOM table (ie, a mini table gets appended each month): snap_dt gives a snapshot of any given month.                                       Within each month however, pk is unique.  This query gives returns NO values:                                                    `select pk, count(*)
from a                                                                                                          where a.snap_dt='2015-08-31' 
              AND        a.sys_num not in ('1234')
group by pk
having count(*) > 1;`

Comment: @appVenture . . . Then look at `b`.  If the duplicates are not in `a`, then they must be in `b`.

Comment: ....No, `b` is a static table...all records are unique on pk. Please also see my 'solution' below - while I have 'solved' for it, I am not clear why moving the filters on `a` and making an inline table is different from keeping those filters on ON clause (like in my original code). (I understand how it is different on keeping it on the final WHERE clause)

Answer (score 0):

@gordon-linoff ... I solved for it by moving the EOM/snap_dt filter on `a` up.

```
    PROC SQL;

    CONNECT TO db2 AS db1 (USER=&dpwuscod. PASSWORD=&dpwpwcod.  DATABASE=&dpwdbnam.);

   CREATE TABLE dbt_info2 AS 

   SELECT * 
   FROM   CONNECTION to db2 
   ( 
             SELECT    b.*, 
                       coalesce(a.pk,b.pk) pk,

             FROM      (      SELECT p.pk,

                              FROM   a p
                              WHERE  p.snap_dt= &snap_dt. 
                              AND    p.sys_num NOT IN ('1234')
                       ) a

             FULL JOIN b 
             ON        a.pk = b.pk );

    DISCONNECT FROM db2;
   QUIT;
```

But, I thought this code is functionally equivalent to my original code. Apparently not, so I am trying to understand how the ON clauses in a FULL JOIN subset a table (and how that is different from an inline WHERE clause  - I understand how that is different from a final WHERE clause).

EDIT:

This is too long for a comment.

This is not functionally equivalent to your original code.  A `FULL OUTER JOIN` takes matching rows from both tables along with *all* rows from both tables where the `ON` clause does not evaluate to true.  So, if you put a condition in the `ON` clause, it doesn't actually filter the rows in the table you are looking at.

When you use a subquery, you are actually filtering out the rows.